# Why Opamp UA741 CN (from ST) is saturating at 0.60V, when vcc=12V,-vcc=0?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqFKQj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

my circuit is shown below.It is saturating at 0.6V,but I am expecting 11V.
What is the reason for it?

Comment: How did you come by this circuit. There is no feedback and it will operate more like a comparator. The output will always saturate.

Comment: Yes i want output to saturate i am using as comparator. The saturation voltage for opamp is 90% of vcc. So ideally the output should be +10.8volts. But i am getting 0.6volts

Comment: I am using as single power supply. So -vcc is grounded

Answer (score 1):

the uA741 opamp does not include the negative rail in its common-mode range.

In this schematic, you have placed the negative rail at 0V.  Also, the negative terminal is at zero volts.  So the opamp is operating outside its common-mode range.  It is not working because it is misapplied.

Comment: i am using this as single power supply, so i have grounded -vcc=0; Since inverting input is greater than non-inverting input, i am expecting +vsat as output. Am i wrong.